# Is there a way to send battery information to another PC?

Tags: power-management, battery

I have two desktops (both running Kubuntu 22.04) plugged into a UPS, but the UPS only has one spot for a USB cable, so only one of them can receive the battery status. Is there a way to have both PCs see the status of the battery? Ideally I would like for both of them to be able to shutdown automatically if the power goes out and the battery gets too low.

Comment: Look up **Network UPS Tools** (AKA nut). It is available in Ubuntu repositories. The documentation including the manual [is available online](https://networkupstools.org/documentation.html). You install `nut` in both computers. Configure `upsmon` as primary for the computer directly connected to the UPS. The other computer(s) should be configured as secondary. I assume both computers are on the home network.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. I had never heard of this before.